# go - function to write to an interface{}

Tags: pointers, go

I want to pass a pointer to something into a function, without knowing its type at compile time, have the function write to it. Here's what I thought would work:

```
func foo(dest interface{}) {
    switch (dest).(type) {
    case *int:
        fmt.Println("got int")
        *dest = 1
    // handle other cases...
    }
}
```

However, calling this with an `*int` input

```
func main() {
    bar := 2
    foo(&bar)
    fmt.Println(bar) // expect 1
}
```

yields the compiler error

`invalid indirect of dest (type interface {})`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this piece of code (btw, you don't need the parens around `dest`), you are basically forgetting the type once you enter a case:

```
func foo(dest interface{}) {
    switch dest.(type) {
    case *int:
        fmt.Println("got int")
        *dest = 1
    // handle other cases...
    }
}
```

That is, dest is still of type interface{} according to the compiler, and that makes `*dest = 1` wrong.

You *could* use more type assertions like this...

```
func foo(dest interface{}) {
    switch dest.(type) {
    case *int:
        fmt.Println("got int")
        *dest.(*int) = 1
        // handle other cases...
    }
}
```

...but a switch that actually 'remembers' the type would be much better (from [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch))

```
func foo(dest interface{}) {
    switch dest := dest.(type) {
    case *int:
        fmt.Println("got int")
        *dest = 1
    // handle other cases...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks :)

Comment: what if dest has an unknown type

Comment: @samix73 I don't understand your question, the function already takes an `interface{}` which is about as unknown as it gets in Go

Comment: @evertheylen I mean what if I use this function to handle too many types, we can't define a switch case for every single type passed to this function

Comment: @samix73 I don't really see your point. In a typed language like Go, you simply can't do much with `dest` if you don't know it's type.

Answer (score 1):

dest is still of type `interface{}`. You have to cast it during the assignment as well:

```
*dest.(*int) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This question seems a bit old, but I have come along a more general way to handle this using reflection, it's not as fast as other solutions but it works with any other types you pass to the function

```
func foo(dest interface{}) {
    destVal := reflect.ValueOf(dest)
    val := reflect.ValueOf(1)
    if destVal.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && destVal.Elem().Kind() == val.Kind() {
        if destElem := destVal.Elem(); destElem.CanSet() {
            destElem.Set(val)
        }
    }
}
```

[example](https://play.golang.org/p/VoNuHf14LD)

Comment: I see what you mean now. However, this smells a whole lot like you just want generics :)